# Is there a CAS that can compute a direct product decomposition of modular group algebras?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, gap, sagemath, magma-cas

Let $G$ be a finite group and $k$ be a finite field of characteristic $p>0$ such that $p\mid |G|$.

> Is there a computer algebra system which can compute a direct product decomposition of such group algebras $kG$?

If yes, I'd be interested in getting the idempotents for the decomposition as output, too.

Remark: We can assume that $G$ is given as a permutation group.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you mean the direct sum decomposition of the regular module? (If so, GAP can do this.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. Sorry that I didn't state that in a clearer way...I meant a decomposition as direct product of $k$-algebras.

Comment: Maybe the sage package https://github.com/nthiery/sage-semigroups could do that, but I am not sure.